# Excel - calculating if a specific time is AM or PM

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to run a time-sheet import excel sheet to our software. It has columns as follows: 'employee name', 'start time', 'end time', and 'total hours'. Problem is that some 'start time' and 'end time' rows don't have AM/PM. When i edit the formatting of the cell it should show if it's AM or PM it just adds AM to all.

example: start time 8:00    end time 3:30    total hours 7.5

In the above example, the end time 3:30 is clearly PM since total hours is 7.5.

Question: is there a formula in excel to add in the start/end time cells whether this time is AM or PM ACCORDING TO THE TOTAL HOURS?

Comment: If the times are all AM as formatting reveals, then when Start is AM and End **should be** PM (but is really stored as AM), `End - Start` should either show no result or the wrong result. Perhaps the time worked is not calculated.

Answer (score 1):

*Basically this happens due to improper TIME Format, applied to cells.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Select Start & End Time Cells, and apply `HH:MM 
  AM/PM` Format.
- Apply `[H]:MM` Time Format to cells, before you 
  apply Formula to get Time Difference.

**N.B.**

- While enter Time in cells, the Time must according to **24 Hrs Clock**, for example `15:30` for `03:30 PM`, since cells has `TIME Format HH:MM AM/PM`.
- In case both `Start & End Time Cells has HH:MM AM/PM` Format and the `Formula cells has GENERAL` better use this Formula.

`=(EndTime-StartTime)*24`.

You get `7.5`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Select the following Time format.

[image]
The `PM` time format shows `AM` and `PM`
*Notice the sample is showing `AM` for the data currently in the cell.*

Comment: If making this change shows AM for all times, then End - Start should either show no result or the wrong result. Perhaps the time worked is not calculated?

Answer (score 0):

#### Import: Use an Excel Sheet, Helper-Column Instead of *End Time* column.

**End Time Helper-Column** `=[StartTime] + [TimeWork]`

- Depending on the software doing the import, this may be a solution
  available in the import script or the import configuration settings.

**Further refinement when start times occur in the PM:**

Start Time Helper-Column `=If([StartTime] > [AM/PM-CutOff], [StartTime], [StartTime] + TIME(12,0,0))`

- Where [AM/PM-CutOff] is `Time(Hours,Mins,Secs)`
- After what *hour:Min* is the Start time definitely AM? *(Is **4:00** an AM or PM start time?)*
- The cut off could be further refined based on the hours worked.